# AssertionError in django

Tags: python, django

I've been pulling my hair out on this one and it seems like there is a really simple solution for it but I'm too blind to see it.
I've upgraded from Django 1.4.3 to Django 1.6 and ever since then I get an assertion error while trying to get DateTimeField to work.

Here's my model

```
class Article(models.Model):
'''Article Model'''

banner = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Banner", null=True, blank=True, upload_to='ajax_uploads/banners', max_length=300)

title = models.CharField(
    verbose_name = _(u'Title'),
    help_text = _(u' '),
    max_length = 255
)
slug = models.SlugField(
    verbose_name = _(u'Slug'),
    help_text = _(u'Uri identifier.'),
    max_length = 255
)
content_markdown = models.TextField(
    verbose_name = _(u'Content (Markup)'),
    help_text = _(u' '),
)
content_markup = models.TextField(
    verbose_name = _(u'Content (Markup)'),
    help_text = _(u' '),
)
categories = models.ManyToManyField(
    Category,
    verbose_name = _(u'Categories'),
    help_text = _(u' '),
    null = True,
    blank = True
)
date_publish = models.DateTimeField(
    default=datetime.date.today,
    verbose_name = _(u'Publish Date'),
    help_text = _(u' ')
)

class Meta:
    app_label = _(u'blog')
    verbose_name = _(u'Article')
    verbose_name_plural = (u'Articles')
    ordering = ['-date_publish']

def save(self):
    self.content_markup = markdown(self.content_markdown, ['codehilite'])
    super(Article, self).save()

def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.title,)
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
'''News index'''
archive_dates = Article.objects.dates('date_publish','month', order='DESC')
categories = Category.objects.all()

page = request.GET.get('page')
article_queryset = Article.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(article_queryset, 5)

try:
    articles = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    #If page requested is not an integer, deliver first page.
    articles = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    #If page requested is out of range, deliver last page of results.
    articles = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render(
    request,
    'blog/article/index.html',
{
    'articles' : articles,
    'archive_dates' : archive_dates,
    'categories' : categories
}
)
```

and template

```
                        <div class="8u skel-cell-important">
                                    {% for item in articles %}
                                            <!-- Content -->
                                                <article class="box is-post">
                                                    <a href="{% url "blog-article-single" slug=item.slug %}" class="image image-full"><img src="/media/{{ item.banner }}" alt="" /></a>
                                                    <header>
                                                        <h2><a href="{% url "blog-article-single" slug=item.slug %}">{{ item.title }}</a></h2>
                                                        <span class="byline">Published {{  item.date_publish|date:"j, M, Y" }}</span>
                                                    </header>
                                                    <p>
                                                        {{ item.content_markup|safe|slice:":250" }}...
                                                    </p>
                                                </article>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                        </div>
```

and finally error traceback:

```
AssertionError at /blog/

'date_publish' is a DateTimeField, not a DateField.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/blog/
Django Version:     1.6.1
Exception Type:     AssertionError
Exception Value:    

'date_publish' is a DateTimeField, not a DateField.

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py in _check_field, line 258
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python2.7
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/user/paperpxl',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']

Server time:    Thu, 19 Dec 2013 15:28:43 +0000
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated!

**EDIT** : Thanks for your help guys, I'm going back to the release notes to read through them again! I wish I had an eye for detail like you do.

Comment: When doing django upgrades it's worth taking time to do them methodically. Even if it's a relatively small/unreleased project. For example upgrade to the latest 1.5 release first. Then if something breaks upgrading from there to 1.6 you can narrow it down to "ok, this is something to do with the 1.6 release"

Comment: I've only realized that my django version changed when I was debugging this error. It seems that one of the apps that I use uninstalled 1.4.3 and installed 1.6 instead.
I keep an eye on my logs from now on. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`date_publish` is a `DateTimeField`, not a `DateField`. Use the [`datetimes()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.datetimes) method instead of `dates()`.

```
Article.objects.datetimes('date_publish', 'month', order='DESC')
```

See the [1.6 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#addition-of-queryset-datetimes) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Django 1.6 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/):

> QuerySet.dates() no longer usable on DateTimeField
>
> QuerySet.dates() raises an error if it’s used on DateTimeField when
>   time zone support is active. Use QuerySet.datetimes() instead.

You use `dates` on the view, with the `date_publish` DateTimeField model.